# Calculation in DevExpress grid

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I have one DevExpress grid in windows form, where its datasource is dynamic and getting bind at runtime.I need to have some calculation to be done on this grid.

**All the columns are dynamic**

Let say grid is having 2 columns **Product** and **Rate** with 300 rows.
Here I need 3rd column let say for ex. Max Rate.

1st cell of this column it should the **maximum rate from 1st 5 ROW**
see bellow example of excel.

[image]
This MAX RATE column could be anything (May be Average or SUM or anything)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @FirstStep
Nope, its simple Windows form application with DevExpress controls.

Answer (score 0):

Use gridview's CustomDrawCell event.

```
private void gridview_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    //assume colMaxRate is your Max Rate column name
    if (e.Column.FieldName == colMaxRate.FieldName) {
        //do your calculation you need, in this example, find max value of next 4 rows including current row
        int maxValue = 0;
        //initialize maxValue to current row's value
        maxValue = gridview.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, colRate.FieldName);
        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 4; rowIndex++) {
            //TODO: do your own checking to make sure you don't exceed last row count
            if (maxValue > gridview.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle + rowIndex, colRate.FieldName)) {
                maxValue = gridview.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle + rowIndex, colRate.FieldName);
            }
        }
        e.DisplayText = maxValue.ToString();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```